# My dynamic array has a SIGSEGV when free()'d, but can be accessed?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, segmentation-fault

I have been having problems with a uneasy to track down segmentation fault lately. The strange thing is, it lets me access the array fine, but for some reason it doesn't allow me to free it without causing the fault. I tested everything to make sure it wasn't anything else, so I can say with 100% certainty that it only occurs at the free line. The confusing thing is that the crash is very selective. As in, it only occurs after I press the help button on the menu in my game, yet it has no problems otherwise. After accessing the help section, it still allows access though, which makes the error even more strange. I may have the wrong idea about segmentation faults, but I'm pretty sure they don't usually allow access even if it isn't a significant error. I know they usually haven't for me. I would post the code here, but my project is very large. I'll try to post the parts of importance.

Here is how I allocate the array :

```
static void zero_array( void * memory, int elements, size_t element_size )
{
    memset( memory, 0, elements * element_size );

    return;
}

/* ******************************************************** */

static void fill_array_with_ones( void * memory, int elements, size_t element_size )
{
    memset( memory, 1, elements * element_size );

    return;
}

/* ******************************************************** */

static void * create_array( int elements, size_t element_size, t_setter setter )
{
    void * temp = NULL;

    if ( !( temp = malloc( elements * element_size ) ) )
    {
        perror( "malloc" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    if ( setter )
        setter( temp, elements, element_size );

    return temp;
}
```

I have tested this many times without problems. I use it mainly for my menu API I use to make it easier to track button events in SDL on bitmap images.

My setup code for the problem area looks like this :

```
extern void setup_mdata( game_data * game, menu * tmenu, const char * menu_image_path, int max_buttons, bool default_handling, t_handle_var_mdata handle_mdata )
{
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    tmenu->max_buttons = max_buttons;
    tmenu->allocation_size = sizeof( bool ) * game->game_menu.max_buttons;

    tmenu->hover_over_button = ( bool * )create_array( max_buttons, sizeof( bool ), zero_array );
    tmenu->is_clicked = ( bool * )create_array( max_buttons, sizeof( bool ), zero_array );
    if ( !default_handling )
        tmenu->is_enabled = ( bool * )create_array( max_buttons, sizeof( bool ), fill_array_with_ones );
    tmenu->button_shape = ( SDL_Rect * )create_array( max_buttons, sizeof( SDL_Rect ), zero_array );

    tmenu->menu_image = load_texture( game->renderer, ( char * )menu_image_path, true, 255, 0, 255 );
    SDL_QueryTexture( game->game_menu.menu_image, NULL, NULL, &width, &height );

    handle_mdata( game, tmenu, width, height );

    return;
}
```

Yet again, I have tested this code many times and it hasn't ever failed on any other menu. Which makes the problem very strange to me.

Here is how I call this function for both the main and help menu for the title screen :

```
setup_mdata( game, &game->title_menu, "bitmaps//title_menu.bmp", 3, true, setup_title_menu );
    setup_mdata( game, &game->title_help_menu, "bitmaps//title_help_menu.bmp", 3, true, setup_title_help_menu );
```

I don't think it matters, but if you're wondering, here is the code to actually setup the menus with additional data.

```
static void setup_title_menu( game_data * game, menu * tmenu, int width, int height )
{
    int nbutton = 0;

    tmenu->button_highlight = ( SDL_Texture ** )create_array( 1, sizeof( SDL_Texture * ), zero_array );
    *tmenu->button_highlight = load_texture( game->renderer, ( char * )"bitmaps//button4_highlight.bmp", true, 255, 255, 255 );

    for ( ; nbutton < tmenu->max_buttons; nbutton++ )
    {
        MB_SHAPE.h = TITLE_BUTTON_HEIGHT;
        MB_SHAPE.w = TITLE_BUTTON_WIDTH;
        MB_SHAPE.x = menu_shape.x + FIRST_TITLE_BUTTON_X;
        MB_SHAPE.y = menu_shape.y + FIRST_TITLE_BUTTON_Y + ( ( TITLE_BUTTON_HEIGHT + TITLE_BUTTON_DIVIDER_HEIGHT ) * nbutton );
    }

    return;
}

/* ******************************************************** */

static void setup_title_help_page_shape( game_data * game )
{
    game->title_screen_data.help_page_shape.h = HELP_PAGE_HEIGHT;
    game->title_screen_data.help_page_shape.w = HELP_PAGE_WIDTH;
    game->title_screen_data.help_page_shape.x = menu_shape.x + 59;
    game->title_screen_data.help_page_shape.y = menu_shape.y + 192;

    return;
}

/* ******************************************************** */

static void setup_title_help_menu( game_data * game, menu * tmenu, int width, int height )
{
    int nbutton = 0;

    tmenu->button_highlight = ( SDL_Texture ** )create_array( 2, sizeof( SDL_Texture * ), zero_array );
    tmenu->button_highlight[0] = load_texture( game->renderer, ( char * )"bitmaps//button2_highlight.bmp", true, 255, 255, 255 );
    tmenu->button_highlight[1] = load_texture( game->renderer, ( char * )"bitmaps//triangle_highlight.bmp", true, 255, 255, 255 );

    setup_title_help_page_shape( game );

    for ( ; nbutton < tmenu->max_buttons; nbutton++ )
    {
        switch ( nbutton )
        {
            case GO_BACK :
                tmenu->button_shape[GO_BACK].h = 50;
                tmenu->button_shape[GO_BACK].w = 120;
                tmenu->button_shape[GO_BACK].x = menu_shape.x + 329;
                tmenu->button_shape[GO_BACK].y = menu_shape.y + 61;
            break;

            case ARROW_RIGHT :
                tmenu->button_shape[ARROW_RIGHT].h = 34;
                tmenu->button_shape[ARROW_RIGHT].w = 17;
                tmenu->button_shape[ARROW_RIGHT].x = menu_shape.x + 432;
                tmenu->button_shape[ARROW_RIGHT].y = menu_shape.y + 473;
            break;

            case ARROW_LEFT :
                tmenu->button_shape[ARROW_LEFT].h = 34;
                tmenu->button_shape[ARROW_LEFT].w = 17;
                tmenu->button_shape[ARROW_LEFT].x = menu_shape.x + 390;
                tmenu->button_shape[ARROW_LEFT].y = menu_shape.y + 473;
            break;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

The part where it actually breaks is when I try to do this :

```
free( game->title_help_menu.is_clicked );
free( game->title_help_menu.hover_over_button );
```

If you're wondering, it doesn't break on the help menu arrays, for whatever reason. Which confuses me even more. I made sure it wasn't anything else by removing these functions, and it didn't throw a SIGSEGV. I figure there is some subtle problem that is causing this, but I have no idea what it is. I'm glad if any of you know more about debugging than I do and can at least make some suggestions on this.

Comment: Are you sure the two free statements only get called once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The strange thing is, it lets me access the array fine, but for some reason it doesn't allow me to free it without causing the fault.

That isn't strange *at all*.

Most UNIX `malloc` implementations do not release `free`d memory to the OS immediately. Instead, they keep it on free-list, in the hope that application will ask for it again, and it will be readily available *without* executing system calls (which are expensive).

> The confusing thing is that the crash is very selective.

That is also *very* typical for heap corruption problems. When you corrupt heap (e.g. by overflowing an allocated buffer, or `free`ing something twice), the crash may come much later, and may go away when you change something unrelated.

Good news: tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and [Address Sanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) usually help you find heap corruption problems very quickly and efficiently.

Comment: I thought it might've been a data corruption problem, and as it turns out, there was something wrong with this member of the structure : `tmenu->allocation_size`. I'm still not sure what made it invalid, but using the formula literally in memset() when zeroing the array instead of that structure member fixed the fault completely. I haven't had any problems since then. I tracked down the problem by moving the free() call around and seeing when it did and didn't crash.